# How to make text that round a picture like a circle?

Tags: inkscape, text

I want to make a logo. The content of the logo is a picture and a sentence which round a picture like a circle. I am using Inkscape (on Ubuntu). Which tools should I use?

If I can't do this on Inkscape, what software should I use?

Answer (score 3):

- Draw a circle in the desired size.
- Convert it into a path.
- Write the text.
- Mark text and circle.
- From the text menu, choose 'align to path'. Since I have a german Inkscape version, the exact wording might differ. Single text + band - I guess the default options.

[image: text around circle]

Note: The circle has to stay in the picture. If you delete the circle, the text will vanish too. If you modify the form, the text will do. Try it out - it can be a useful feature. But you can remove the color of the circle (and of its outline, if there is any). But you should group circle and text first - else they may be moved to different locations and later you might get curious about the circle, maybe in outline view, and delete or modify it accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeat the instructions - try [Youtube tutorial here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJI6CHcQr-U).

Comment: Please explain in words as well, in case the link becomes broken in the future.

Comment: Sure enough Kami said to repeat in words just in case the link gets broken...... The link is broken. wow. And the way he explained it, he's missing an instruction because when I went to do my text, it ends up, upside down and on top. I know this is an old post but I will put my two cents i so when others browse and find like I did, they will know how to do it right.